# SpriteKit bodyWithTexture gap between sprites when colliding

Tags: sprite-kit

I'm new to SpriteKit and I'm trying to create a game, where blocks would fall from top of the screen and land on the bottom of the screen or on top of another block. Here is the sample code from GameScene.m:

```
- (void)didMoveToView:(SKView *)view 
{
    self.size = CGSizeMake(view.frame.size.width, view.frame.size.height);
    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    self.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithEdgeLoopFromRect:self.frame];

    SKSpriteNode *redRect = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"RedRect"];
    redRect.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), self.frame.size.height);
    redRect.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithTexture:redRect.texture size:redRect.texture.size];
    redRect.physicsBody.affectedByGravity = YES;

    SKSpriteNode *blueRect = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"BlueRect"];
    blueRect.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), self.frame.size.height);
    blueRect.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithTexture:blueRect.texture size:blueRect.texture.size];
    blueRect.physicsBody.affectedByGravity = YES;

    [self addChild:redRect];
    [self addChild:blueRect];
}
```

As you can see on the screenshot, there is a gap between the two blocks and between the red block and the ground. This only happens when rects collide with each other or with the ground. For instance, if I use the `SKAction moveToY:` which moves the block to the bottom of the screen, the gap disappears. How can I get rid of these gaps when the nodes collide?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am totally sure that the problem is about your texture images, They are not precisely cropped or even created.

`Spritekit` engine never creates gaps between nodes.

Comment: My bad, you were right, my images had invisible border around them and it took me 2 days to notice!